# Quicker copying of code examples

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

There are some code snippets in answers that I want to take, but it is slightly inconvenient to select the whole thing. Could there be a button added next to every snippet that lets you copy the whole thing to clipboard?

Comment: Good suggestion, but already suggested: see the first answer on the linked question.

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow's *The Key*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411816/can-i-actually-buy-a-copy-paste-keyboard-like-the-stack-overflow-april-fools-t/411817#411817) (a physical product)